# Draw axis thru x=0 and y=0

Tags: flot

I have a set of data that I'm plotting as a scatter graph which has both positive and negative values on both axis. When I plot this in Flot, the axis are draw at the bottom and the left by default. Is there a way to make it draw the axis through the center of the graph? @X=0 and Y=0?

In other words, instead of this:

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible in the default flot.  I'm sure it could be hacked in if you wanted to dig into the source, but flot by itself only supports left/right for the y-axis, and top/bottom for the x-axis.

Comment: Well that sucks. However, I'm looking now into writing a plugin. Which is causing me other problems...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430832/where-did-the-drawbackground-hook-go-or-why-is-my-last-point-the-wrong-color

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else comes across the same need, I created a plugin for Flot and put it here:

https://github.com/burlandm/Flot-Origin-Axis

It does what I need, but I won't make any promises that it'll fit your particular scenario. If I have time, I might try and update it to cover more scenarios.